# Как удалить только одно значение из sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Как переделать этот код чтоб удалял только одно значение, а не все записи с тем же именем в таблице?

```
        if request.form["submit_button"] == "Удалить город":
        del_city = request.form["add_city"]
        with sq.connect("data.bd") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lst (name TEXT)""")
            cur.execute(f"""DELETE FROM lst WHERE name=?""",(del_city,))
```

Comment: Надо определиться с однозначными критериями, по которым нужно удалять. Если названия города недостаточно, то как СУБД должно понять, какую именно строку надо удалить? Или надо удалить не всю строку, а какое-то поле в строке?

Comment: В БД только города, нужно удалить город, неважно с конца или начала

Comment: А в чём смысл такой таблицы? Если нужно считать количество, лучше уж сделать два поля. Название города и количество. И когда нужно менять количество в большую или меньшую сторону.

Comment: https://imgur.com/SMelUrE.png

Answer (score 0):

Так удалить только одну строку:

```sql
DELETE FROM lst WHERE rowid IN (
  SELECT rowid FROM lst WHERE name=? LIMIT 1)
```

И как заметили в комментариях, у вас что то не так со структурой таблиц.